# Question about the Ham sandwich theorem.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image: The Problem][image: The problem continued( top part only disregard question 30)]

The question I’m referring to is question 29. As it states I have to find an prove that for any angle theta between 0 and pi , it is possible to cut the slice in half with a cut of incline theta.

I am so confused by this question and honestly have no idea where to start. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You have to show that the function $A$ is continous. Then, since $A(b_1)=A$ and $A(b_2)= -A$, what can you say about the values of A when $b$ is between $b_1$ and $b_2$ ?

Comment: The values of A are between A and -A?

Comment: Yes. And? What does the IVT = Intermediate Value Theorem then tell you?

Comment: There exists a value of b where the amount of ham to the left equals the amount of ham to the right? If so, how do I relate this to theta? The question asks me to find the values of theta for which the ham can be cut in half with an incline of theta.

Comment: You don't have to find theta. If you read the exercise carefully, it sais " prove that for any angle theta...".   In other words, you have to show that no matter what theta is, it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we reason when the line is not vertical:

Let $ 0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, $\theta \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$ denote your favorite angle. Then the equation
$$y= tan(\theta)x+b$$
defines a straight line with incline $\theta$, crossing the y axis in the point $(0,b)$. If you vary the value of $b$, you will see that the line is moved vertically up and down.(but changing $b$ does not change the incline! In other words, the steepness of the line stays the same)

Now, this line divides the plane into two pieces. Call one of the pieces $P_1$ and the other $P_2$.

Now we imagine that we have a piece of ham with area $A$ lying on the plane, and define $$A(b)=\overset{\text{area of ham that lies}}{\text{in plane $P_1$}}-\overset{\text{area of ham that lies}}{\text{in plane $P_2$}}$$

Now, the function $A$ is continous(you don't need to prove this). Also, $A(b_1)=A$ and $A(b_2)=-A$ for some values $b_1$ and $b_2$ of $b$ (because we can move the line either completely to one side of the ham, or completely to the other side of the ham.)

By the IVM=intermediate Value Theorem, there is a value of $b$, say $b_0$, that is between $b_1$ and $b_2$ and such that 
$$A(b_0)=0$$
But this simply means that the line with incline $\theta$ that crosses the y -axis in the point $(0,b_0)$ divides the ham into two pieces of equal area. Since the angle $\theta$ was not specified, it is true for every $\theta.$ In other words: No matter which incline we choose, we can find a line with that incline that divides the ham in two pieces.

Comment: What does the variable x mean? Is x equal to theta?

Comment: Also why is the function A(b)? Shouldn't it be A(x) instead?

Comment: What is the value of x?

Comment: I have modified the answer to make it more understandable. Also, be careful to note that in the Exercise, the author has chosen to use the letter $A$ for both the area of the ham **and** the function $A$! (These are two different things!)

Comment: What if the line was vertical?

Comment: If the line is vertical, then the line is given by the equation $x = b$ where $b$ is a constant. If we change the value of $b$, we move the line horisontally (left or right). In this case, we can define the function $A$ by $A(b)$ equals the area of ham to the left of the line minus the area of the ham to the right of the line.   As before, the function $A$ is continous. Also, if $b$ is large **enough**, then $A(b)$ equals the area of the ham (line is placed to the right of the ham), and if $b$ is small enough and negative, $A(b)$ equals minus the area of the ham. $A(b_0)=0$  for some $b_0$.

Comment: Did you understand it in the end? : )

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of it, thanks